# baseDN on ldapsearch vs ldapadd

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am learning to use OpenLDAP and I can not understand why you need to specify a base dn to search in the ldap tree but you do not need it in order to add stuff

```
ldapsearch -x -b "dc=foo,dc=local"
ldapadd -x -W -D "dn=admin,dc=foo,dc=local" -f ou.ldif
```

Can somebody explained me the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The command-line tool *ldapadd* expects full DNs of new entries to be specified in the LDIF input. This is because each add operation must contain the full DN of a new entry to be added. *ldapadd* tool reads multiple new entries from LDIF entry records and sends an add operation for each of them.

See also: [RFC 4511, section 4.7 - Add Operation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4511#section-4.7)

In opposite the tool *ldapsearch* sends a search operation. And this must have a "base DN" or "search root" specified.

See also: [RFC 4511, section 4.5.1 - Search Request](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4511#section-4.5.1)